# getting error "Failed to get version of function(null)" in Intellij while running azure function

Tags: azure, intellij-idea, azure-functions, azure-java-sdk, azure-java-tools

I am trying to run azure function in local in intellij.
While I run in local, I get this error in intellij :
[image]

when I click on configure, I see that the path is set correctly.
[image]

Now, I have tried uninstalling the current azure tools, and installing through npm or through installer. But nothing worked.

I have also tried the version 3 instead of 4 for azure tools, that also didnt help.

Any idea how to resolve this? Nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 2):

I have tested in my system - IntelliJ IDE - Java Azure Functions Project, it is running successfully.

[image]

As I observed in your IDE Azure Sign In Tool

[image]

the functions core tools path is different compared to my IntelliJ IDE Configuration.

[image]

Replace the Functions core tools path with the path as I have shown below, in your IDE and run the function once.

`C:\Users\<YourUserFolder>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\func.exe`

And even in the run configuration also, it should be same:

[image]

Comment: you seem to have installed through npm and I have installed through installer. But anyways, even if I install it through npm, error is still the same.

Comment: Did you modify the path as I mentioned in the answer? If not, modify and check once.

Comment: this is what i informed you

Comment: for me it was the path, thanks for help